# R : How to let it recognize the file path it should find?

Tags: r, filepath

For example , i have to read this files , but however when it switches to another computer it would not recognize the file path for Eric since other computer would not have Eric one them.

```
       pos = readLines("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\projects\\positive_words.txt")
       neg = readLines("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\projects\\negative_words.txt")
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: would it help to use `filepath <- file.choose()` choose the right file interactively so you dont have to write the path manually and afterwards you could use the `filepath` to read in the data, e.g. data <- read.csv(filepath, sep=";")

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your problem in detail. Relative paths can certainly be a solution. But you could also search for the pathname. If the filenames are unique within the folder that you search, this works:

```
pospath <- list.files("C:/Users/",pattern="^positive_words.txt$", recursive = TRUE,full.names = TRUE)
negpath <- list.files("C:/Users/",pattern="^negative_words.txt$", recursive = TRUE,full.names = TRUE)

pos=readLines(pospath)
neg=readLines(negpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use [relative paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29)

Comment: I have never used relative paths before :/ and especially on R.
Any clue or tips would be very helpful thanks!
I'm gonna google on it meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should set the working directory. Then, whenever you are working in another computer you just change that line of code, as all file names are expressed relative to the working directory:

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\projects")
pos = readLines("positive_words.txt")
neg = readLines("negative_words.txt")
```